# Binary diff algorithm for commercial software

Tags: diff, binary-diff, librsync

I'm working on application sending changed files to other computers. Currently a changed file is sent completely even if the change is minor. I'm looking for a library (C,C++,Java) that would allow me to create a binary diff and send only the delta and the matching patch to merge the data back.

I'm looking for something ideally under an Eclipse or Apache licence. LGPL would work too.

Comment: *zstd --patch-from* is a new contender

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- [Open VCDiff](https://github.com/google/open-vcdiff) c++, ASL 2.0
- [Java xdelta](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaxdelta/) Java, MIT
- [librsync](https://github.com/librsync/librsync) c/c++. LGPL

Answer (score 4):

[bsdiff and bspatch](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) are not libraries but you could extract the C source code without too much effort and the license should also work for you.